# Cypress: How do I visit, or type a generated URL into the Cypress browser

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-mailosaur

I currently have an email SMTP server that sends an email, that generates a URL.

I am able to get the contents of the URL from the email, but I want to then visit, or type this URL into the current Cypress address bar.
[image: Cypress Runner Log - URL Example]

The code I have in Cypress looks like this.
[image: CypressExample.js]

And the line of code related in the feature file looks like this.
[image: CypressExample.feature]

When I run the Cypress code is get this error.
[image: CypressError]

Is there anyway I can use this generated URL and insert it into the Cypress address bar?

Comment: try logging in `email.text.links[0].value`. As per your error this is not translating into a valid URL.

Comment: Can you copy cy.mailosaurGetMessage custom command? Actually log would be more helpful to see what this command yielded exactly.
I believe it returns/yields something but not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you need is `.href` rather than `.value`

```js
cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
  sentTo: testEmail
}).then(email => {
  cy.visit(email.text.links[0].href)
})
```